# Python/OS X: Installed OpenCV from source, but import cv2 results in ImportError

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew

I downloaded the OpenCV source tarball from http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary, and I performed the following steps:

1. Decompressed the tarball
2. cd ~/opencv
3. mkdir release
4. cd release
5. cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
   ..
6. make
7. sudo make install

Now, when I try to do `import cv2` I get an ImportError:

```
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

**NOTE: This is for Mac OS X**

Comment: How did you install python on your machine?

Comment: I used `brew install python`. I have successfully installed opencv this time by following these steps: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/

Comment: Since you brewed python, you could have tried: `brew install opencv3 --with-python`

Comment: That would have been a faster solution, especially since I did not need the fine control that compiling from source offered. I just looked it up, and the same blog site that had the tutorial I mentioned also offered that as a simpler solution, albeit at a cost of reduced control: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing, following these instructions successfully installed Python opencv on Mac OS X for me: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/

There is an older version of that tutorial, but it had issues with macOS Sierra, so make sure you are following the most recent version. Also, be careful not to just copy and paste everything, especially commands with arguments or flags with situation-specific values, such as paths. For example, if you are not using virtualenv, make sure to replace the virtualenv-based paths with your local Python installation paths. This is particularly important when filling out the `cmake` flag fields when you get to that step.

Also, as Quang Hoang mentioned, doing `brew install opencv3 --with-python` could be a faster alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to download the whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

1. open the site
2. find and search the opencv
3. download the whl files according to your pc specs
4. download

Open the cmd in directory in which whl file is installed and type:

```
pip install file-name.whl
```

It worked for me, I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Hello Muhammad thank you for your response, but I am working with Mac OS X, and those binaries are for Windows.